Generating the report form sonarqube using gitlab ci getting error
Issue: SonarQube Report Not Generated in GitLab CI
I'm using GitLab CI for code quality checks with SonarQube. My SonarQube instance is running on an EC2 virtual machine, and I'm using the SonarQube CLI to push the code quality reports to SonarQube. However, I'm encountering an issue where the report is not being generated.
GitLab CI Configuration
.gitlab-ci.yml
sonarqube-check:
  stage: analysis
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
    SONAR_URL: "http://143.127.12.15:9000"
    SONAR_TOKEN: $SONAR_TOKEN
  cache:
    key: php_vendor
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - sonar-scanner
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - report.json
  allow_failure: true

sonarqube_report_download:
  stage: download
  image:
    name: alpine:latest
  needs: ["sonarqube-check"]
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add curl
    - mkdir -p Sonar_Report
    - curl -u $SONAR_TOKEN "$SONAR_URL/api/issues/search?projectKeys=phpprojecttest" -o Sonar_Report/report.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - Sonar_Report/report.json

This is sonar-properties
sonar.projectKey=phpprojecttest
sonar.projectName=phptest
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.host.url=http://143.127.12.75:9000
sonar.login=sqp_fc4da4b3b4a22b221045463956

sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=**/vendor/**

sonar.tests=tests
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.test.php
sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml

Here I need to Generate the Sonarqube Report.json or xml file which i need to upload in the defectdojo.
